# Route to port by path with traefik

Tags: traefik, portainer

Can't access my home portainer via traefik set up on VPS.

I have a VPS with a public IP and a Wireguard server installed. My home machine with Ubuntu Server is connected to the vps via wireguard. I can ping the home server (ip: 10.0.0.4). I can't connect through vps to Portainer on my home server through the path (/portainer), it shows `404 page not found`, but i can see routing rules in traefik dashboard. I'm running traefik via Docker with exposed 80 and 8080 ports. How can I solve this problem?
Static configuration (/etc/traefik/traefik.yml):

```
providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/conf.d
    watch: true

global:
  checkNewVersion: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: :80

api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
```

Dynamic configuration (/etc/traefik/conf.d/config.yml):

```
http:
  routers:
    portainer-router:
      rule: PathPrefix(`/portainer`)
      service: portainer-service

  services:
    portainer-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://10.0.0.4:9000/
        passHostHeader: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove path (probably because portainer can't work with subpaths). Working config.yml:

```
  routers:
    portainer-router:
      entryPoints:
        - http
      rule: PathPrefix(`/portainer`)
      middlewares:
        - stripPortainerPrefix
      service: portainer-service

  middlewares:
    stripPortainerPrefix:
      stripPrefix:
        prefixes:
          - "/portainer"

  services:
    portainer-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://10.0.0.4:9000/
        passHostHeader: false
```